# Installing Photoshop CS5 on Ubuntu 12.10 using Wine

Tags: wine, winetricks

I have a problem during installation of Photoshop CS5. 
When I open up the installer using Wine, it appers, I make few steps, and when I get to the installation (when the bar starts to move from left to right, and %.. you know) it stops and writes an error.

I tried to install the Photoshop CS4 but it still will not install successfully. 
So please, if you can help me somehow, or post a link that will help me, please do it.

P.S.: I do not want to use the other programs like Gimp, or others, because they are not so good to me like Photoshop. 
Thank you!

(BTW: I am using Ubuntu 12.10, x64, 4GB, 500GB HDD, 1GB Nvidia 220M CUDA, Intel Dual-Core 2,2GHz...)

Answer (score 2):

We've been through this before...as far as installing Photoshop in WINE and Other Emulators.

The best thing to do is visit winehq http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20158 and check the details there.

The detail that is put into the tutorial is better left there. Please use the recommendations from WineHQ

EDIT

Wrong. The best thing to do is to run a VM such as oracle and host Windows XP then install it there. Lightroom works great like that.

Comment: yeah but it's dead slow unless you have 16GB ram and a lightspeed SSD... in which case you run Win7 natively and Ubuntu on the VM :-)